# Non trivial covering space of a finite set

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Let $X=\{ x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4} \}$.

Let $\mathcal{B}= \{ \{ x_{1}\}, \{ x_{3}\} , \{ x_{1},x_{2},x_{3} \} , \{ x_{1},x_{3},x_{4} \} \}$ be a basis for a topology on $X$.

I am trying to find a covering space of this space other than $X$ itself.

I was thinking about taking a bouquet of 4 circles, and mapping each circle to one of the points. Would this work as a covering map? I'm not sure it would be a homeomorphism when restricted.

Or instead maybe define a map from each circle into one of the elements of the basis, since this would allow each point in $X$ to have an evenly covered neighbourhood, but I cannot see how to define this map explicitly.

Comment: Try $\{x_n\mid n=...,-2,-1,0,1,2,...\}$ with the topology $\{x_{2n-1}\}$ and $\{x_{2n-1},x_{2n},x_{2n+1}\}$. You can then map $x_{4k+j}$ to $x_j$, for $j=1,2,3,4$.

Comment: You're not going to find a covering space that involves circles because you need some finite sets to be open.

Comment: You example does not work. Suppose $f : S^1 \to X$ were a covering map. For each $y \in S^1$, letting $x=f(y) \in X$, there would exist $U \subset X$ an evenly covered neighborhood of $x$, and there would exist a neighborhood of $V \subset S^1$ of $y$, such that $f$ restricts to a homeomorphism $f : V \to U$. But $V$ is uncountable and $U$ is finite, so there there cannot even exist a bijection from $V$ to $U$, let alone a homeomorphism.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე thanks, that set works. So would any countable set be a covering space then? Could I use the integers for example?

Comment: Along these lines I believe all countable ones will be in fact equivalent to each other. You can however try to make *finite* coverings out of them, by making it 8, 16, 24, ... etc. periodic

Comment: Could you in fact just use the discrete topology for the countable set then?

Comment: No - since every point of the covering must have a neighborhood mapping homeomorphically to its image, a discrete space cannot be a covering of a non-discrete one

Answer (score 1):

If you have any covering map $p : Y \to X$, then the fibers $p^{-1}(x)$ are discrete. Thus your suggestion does not work. However, if $F$ is any discrete space, then the projection $\pi : X \times F \to X$ is always a covering map.

For $F = \mathbb Z$ this resembles მამუკა ჯიბლაძე's example. A basis of open sets of $X \times F$ is given by the $B \times \{n\}$, where $B \in \mathcal B$ and $n \in  \mathbb Z$. Now identify the set $X \times \mathbb Z$ with $\mathbb Z$ via the bijection $f(x_i,n) = 4n+i$. Then $f(\{x_1 \} \times \{n\}) = \{4n+1 \}$, $f(\{x_3 \} \times \{n\}) = \{4n+3 \}$, $f(\{x_1 \} \times \{n\}) = \{4n+1 \}$, $f(\{x_1,x_2,x_3 \} \times \{n\}) = \{4n+1,4n+2,4n+3 \}$, $f(\{x_1,x_3,x_4 \} \times \{n\}) = \{4n+1,4n+3,4n+4 \}$.

Note that Mamuka Jibladze took $\{4n+3,4n+4,4n+5 \}$ instead of the last set.